# Удобное дерево обзора структуры кода

Tags: c#, классы, ide, обозреватель

Есть ли плагин к VisualStudio для удобного отображения делегатов, анонимных функций, классов, подклассов и переменных/методов объявленных в них.

Стандартное отображение не устраивает, приходится постоянно щелкать по классам чтобы посмотреть во второй половинке окна Обозревателя классов что же находится в этом классе. Понравилось как это сделано в MonoDevelop, без всякой беготни можно открыть несколько узлов дерева и посмотреть внутренности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то вроде [Solution Navigator](https://web.archive.org/web/20151201020846/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/07/20/solution-navigator-blog-post.aspx) из Productivity Power Tools?

Comment: жалко там нет визуальной вложенности классов, ну и на том спасибо